# Prevent vue component from mounting with v-if while preserving transition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In the below code I have built a modal with vue. The problem I am running into is trying to preserve the transition and conditionally mount the vue component. When the button is clicked in the first code block, the modal opens and then `mounted` is logged to the console. This is the behavior I want and the modal does fade in because of the appear attribute.

It does not fade out though because of the `v-if`. I want the transition to continue to work while keeping the v-if because that delays the mounted and unmounted hooks.

The reason I want to keep the `v-if="showModal` is because on iOS there are notorious problems with modals and what I want to do is set the body to `position: fixed` and set the top property inside the modal components onMounted hook. If I were to remove `v-if="showModal"` then the modal component is mounted on page load and I don't want this.

```js
<script setup>
const showModal = ref(false)
</script>

<button @click="showModal = true">show modal</button>

<Teleport to=".vue-modal-target">
  <Modal :show="showModal" @close="showModal = false" v-if="showModal">
    <ContactForm />
  </Modal>
</Teleport>
```

In the `Modal.vue` file I have this

```js
<script setup>
onMounted(() => {
  console.log('mounted')
})

onUnmounted(() => {
  console.log('unmounted')
})
</script>

<template>
  <Transition appear name="modal">
    <div v-if="show" class="modal-wrapper">
      <div class="modal-mask"></div>
      <div class="modal-container">
        <button class="close-btn" @click="$emit('close')" style="color: #fff;">X</button>
        <div class="modal-container__inner">
          <slot />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Transition>
</template>

<style>
.modal-enter-from,
.modal-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-enter-to,
.modal-leave-from {
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-enter-active,
.modal-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
</style>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the code I used based on the recommendation in the accepted answer.

```js
<script setup>
const showModal = ref(false)
</script>

<button @click="showModal = true">show modal</button>

<Teleport to=".vue-modal-target">
  <Modal :show="showModal" @close="showModal = false" v-if="showModal">
    <ContactForm />
  </Modal>
</Teleport>
```

and in the `Modal.vue` file

```js
<script setup>
onMounted(() => {
  console.log('mounted')
})

onUnmounted(() => {
  console.log('unmounted')
})

const props = defineProps({
  show: Boolean
})

const showModal = ref(false)

if (props.show === true) showModal.value = true

const emit = defineEmits(['close'])

function handleClose() {
  showModal.value = false
  setTimeout(() => {
    emit('close')
  }, 500)
}
</script>

<template>
  <Transition appear name="modal">
    <div v-if="showModal" class="modal-wrapper">
      <div class="modal-mask"></div>
      <div class="modal-container">
        <button class="close-btn" @click="handleClose" style="color: #fff;">X</button>
        <div class="modal-container__inner">
          <slot />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Transition>
</template>

<style>
.modal-enter-from,
.modal-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-enter-to,
.modal-leave-from {
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-enter-active,
.modal-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think why it is not showing the transition on closing is because on close you are emitting the event `close` this is caught in the parent and handles the v-if on the component, i think if you want a transition on the modal on leave you should set the `v-if="show"` to false before setting the other v-if to false. With something like a function that sets `this.show = false` and then after calls `this.$emit('close')`

Comment: I need the unmounted hook to fire though thats why I was catching it on the parent.

Comment: You can still do that but for.the animation you need to toggle `show` to `false` first

Comment: I got it to work the way it is supposed to, I feel like there is a cleaner way to do this but I'm not sure

Comment: You can also move the transition to the parent component I think. And what do you mean the way it is supposed to?